# SoapUI specify alternate logdir as a property defined on the command line

Tags: log4j, soapui

I'm upgrading from SoapUI 5.4.0 to 5.7.0 and trying to put the log files in a specific directory.  Note: The alternate error logs directory was working prior to the upgrade.

I have both the following specified in my JAVA_OPTS for SoapUITestCaseRunner

```
-Dsoapui.logroot="%SOAPUI_LOGSDIR%"
-Dsoapui.log4j.config="%SOAPUI_HOME%/soapui-log4j.xml"
```

In my soapui-log4j.xml I specify the error file as:

```
<RollingFile name="ERRORFILE"
     fileName="${soapui.logroot}/soapui-errors.log"
     filePattern="${soapui.logroot}/soapui-errors.log.%i"
     append="true">
```

The error file then gets created without resolving ${soapui.logroot} e.g.

```
$ find . -name "*errors*"
./${soapui.logroot}/soapui-errors.log
```

I also tried it as lookup but ended up with this:

```
ERROR Unable to create file ${sys:soapui.logroot}/soapui-errors.log java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Am I missing anything? Any ideas for next steps?

Answer (score 0):

I tried replacing

```
fileName="${soapui.logroot}/soapui-errors.log"
```

with

```
fileName="${sys:soapui.logroot}/soapui-errors.log"
```

and it worked for me.
I no longer see unresolved '${soapui.logroot}' directory created.

A